# Android ListView with Multiselect not deselecting items

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

I have a multi-select `listview` where I want to keep track of what the user has selected and what they have deselected. When a user clicks on a list item, I add the clicked items into an `ArrayList` and when they click it again I remove the item from the `ArrayList`. The issue is that the deselect operation(when a user clicks on an item already clicked on earlier) is adding into the `ArrayList` again instead of removing.
Below is the code for `onListItemClick` for that activity:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_forEasyPayListItem);
        int stringPos = 0;
        selectedBiller = billerNamesArray[position];
        selectedBillerAccountNumber = billerAccountsArray[position];
        selectedBillerBalance = billerToPayBalances[position];

        SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = lstPayMyBills.getCheckedItemPositions();
        if (sparseBooleanArray != null && sparseBooleanArray.size() > 0) {
            for (int index = 0; index < sparseBooleanArray.size(); index++) {
                if (sparseBooleanArray.valueAt(index)) {
                    lstPayMyBills.setItemChecked(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(index), true);
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    selectedItems.add(new PayMyBillsListItemModel(position, selectedBiller, selectedBillerAccountNumber, selectedBillerBalance));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Array size is " + selectedItems.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    lstPayMyBills.setItemChecked(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(index), false);
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                    //selectedItems.remove(new PayMyBillsListItemModel(position, selectedBiller, selectedBillerAccountNumber, selectedBillerBalance));
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int index = 0; index < lstPayMyBills.getCount(); index++) {
                lstPayMyBills.setItemChecked(index, true);
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
                selectedItems.remove(new PayMyBillsListItemModel(position, selectedBiller, selectedBillerAccountNumber, selectedBillerBalance));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Array size is " + selectedItems.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }          
    }
```

Comment: I believe you have to remember the object while `selectedItems.add`ing and then call the `remove` method on it, not on a new object.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be that you are creating a new object to remove. if you had a list of "A", "B", "C", "D", "B" and you called remove("B") your list would be:

"A", "C", "D", "B" (removes first occurrence). I think you would have to look for the object in your selected list which matches the one deselected then remove that.

I am not sure on the behavior removing a new object?

Comment: Hello Hughzi, it works well with the first list item, but on clicking the 2nd list item, the app crashes with a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: @user4651322 Could you post me your adapter class?